# What routing/topology protocol(s) should be used with P2P devices with sporadic, changing connectivity?

Tags: routing, multicast, point-to-point-protocol, spanning-tree, topology

I have several IoT devices that will sporadically come into and out of range, and connect in a partial mesh topology.  For illustration purposes, imagine the interconnectivity of a Web of Trust, or Social Graph ... each has similar properties.

- What protocols are able to handle sporadic connectivity, and limit inefficient circular routing?

This is part of a P2P emergency notification solution, where we can assume that cellular service is interrupted or at capacity.

Comment: So, it depends a lot on the infrastructure. How access points connect to each other? What is the convergence time required? What is the SLA of the network that interconnects the access points? Could you elaborate more on your expectations? There will be no one-size-fits-all.

Comment: For p2p connectivity BTLe, (L2CAP, GAAT...any layer), AdHoc Wifi ... all is a mobile phone or IoT device @PEdroArthur

Comment: What do you mean by IoT?  Zigbee devices will spontaneously mesh in a power efficient way, for example.  Your question isn't really...a question.  I mean, off the top of my head, OSPF, EIGRP, BGP, Ad-Hoc WIFI, 802.11s...there must be many more

Comment: @quadruplebucky Can you help me create a logical grouping of technologies or attributes that are beneficial to solving this need? I can leverage this to create a more formal scientific purpose-driven inquiry & experimentation

Comment: Check how the guys from goTenna and Sonnet on kickstarter are doing their off the grid mesh network - they're both kickstarter projects. Spoiler: It's basically SDR.

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444120/ is something I was very interested in and may help with a framework for your problem.  It does not get into routing protocols at all (zigbee).  You may have better luck at networkengineering.stackexchange.com,   this is all OT.